# git и sftp интеграция в sublime text 3

Tags: git, sublime-text, sftp

через саблайм по SSH подключился к сайту

1) как в саблайме в сайд бар вывести дерево удаленного репозитория сайта?
сайт 100гб, по этому локально скачать сайт не предлогать.
перемещаться по файлам через command pallete крайне долго.

2) как через саблайм прямо с сайта к которому я подключен, пушить изменения в битбакет?

Comment: Я с саблаймом не знаком, но пушить просто через терминал его должно быть можно без проблем (терминал ssh соединения соответственно). А вывести дерево файлов гита кажется нигде нельзя (по крайней мере для редактирования), чем дерево самого сайта не устраивает? оно же актуально с гитом. И вы 100гб в гите храните?

Comment: я и хотел дерево сайта, просто выразился не правильно. Как его в сайд бар получить?

Comment: тут не могу помочь, в jetbrains это делается в настройках deployment сервера.

Comment: В [вашем соседнем вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564694/git-gui-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-ssh) я дал рекомендации. Как раз можете совершенно спокойно редактировать в своём любимом текстовом редакторе локальную копию.

Comment: А в этом вопросе даже сам сайт stackoverflow показывает боковую панельку с похожими вопросами. Например, можно увидеть, что есть гит-плагин для sublime -- можете попробовать его.