# git gui с подключением по ssh

Tags: git, битрикс, ssh

мне нужен какой то визуализатор гита, что б можно было все делать в 2 клика, причем делать это прямо на сайте
потому что сейчас я по ssh подключаюсь к сайту и из него через консоль пушу изменения и приходится каждый раз вводить парольи на это уходит много времени

локальное хранение копии сайта не подходит так как сайт работает на битриксе, а там 100000+ файлов.

Comment: `и приходится каждый раз вводить пароль` — используйте авторизацию не по паролю, а по SSH-ключу.

Comment: Гит при каждом пуше передаёт не все файлы, а только архивы изменившихся, упакованные в ещё один архив. Это довольно немного, только если вы не закоммитите папку с фильмами. Немного подробностей тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/126895/181472

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы привыкли к рабочему месту на windows и с него подключаетесь к серверу, то я вам предлагаю попробовать такую схему работы.

Положите сайт в гит. Один из наиболее простых "визуализаторов" гит как вы выразились или гит-клиент -- это программа Source Tree.

При этом папку `bitrix` создайте как отдельный репозиторий и подключите его как submodule к основному проекту. В современных версиях битрикс нет никакой необходимости править файлы ядра, все ваши файлы будут лежать в папке `local`.

Работайте на своей рабочей машине как обычно -- openserver, локальная копия. Проверили версию, залили в гит -- для обновления сервера достаточно зайти на него по SSH (весьма рекомендую входить по SSH ключу с пробросом авторизации) и весь ваш деплой на продакшн будет сводиться к единственной команде `git pull` (даже пароль вводить не придётся, т.к. форвард агента)

Эта схема позволяет разделить developer окружение и production, очень проста и вы на базе её сможете потом постепенно придумывать более сложные схемы.

Также у вас отпадёт [ваш вопрос про sublime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564590/git-%D0%B8-sftp-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-sublime-text-3).

Переживать за большое количество файлов нет никакой необходимости. Из личного опыта могу сказать, что сайты на базе битрикс совершенно спокойно складываются в гит и работа с ними идёт без всяких проблем. На сайте битрикс можно найти много статей, где рекомендуются те или иные способы совместной работы с битрикс и гит. Также наши подрядчики (сертифицированные партнёры Битрикс, с "золотым" статусом) используют гит и битрикс и тоже нет проблем.

Comment: Прочитал вопрос и ответ, весьма озадачен. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin Чем именно?

Comment: (Видимо, пропустил комментарий). Озадачен был как бы это сказать... тем, насколько неудобный способ использовал автор. И придуманным термином «визуализатор гита». :)